# Exclude lines results that have NULL value in any field?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have  a simple Select like this

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE fk_id=10020
```

It's works, but there are some fields that is NULL. There isn't a pattern so a did

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE fk_id=10020 AND NOT NULL
```

trying to select only results with all fields with data.

but did not worked, Results in a Empty Results, it did not bring anything.

How could I do this - exclude lines results that have null value in any field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
SELECT * FROM `table` where fk_id=10020 and data IS NOT NULL
```

repeat `<column> IS NOT NULL` for each column you need

Comment: this is an approach, but is there a way to do that with only one command, because if there are a lot of columns, it will get enormous. Of course this is not a problem, just to know if there are a way to automatize this...

Comment: As far as I know you can't automatize at SQL level. May be wrinting of small method at java\php\python (whatever you use) will help you

Comment: @xander27 Actually it is doable in pure MySQL

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE fk_id = 10020 AND
      fk_id IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

> [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11795340/exclude-lines-results-that-have-null-value-in-any-field#comment15671188_11795360)
>
> *this is an approach, but is there a way to do that with only one command, because if there are a lot of columns, it will get enormous. Of course this is not a problem, just to know if there are a way to automatize this.*

There is a way to avoid specifying each column (maybe not best from performance point of view but it should be more than enough):

```
CREATE TABLE tab(id INT PRIMARY KEY,fk_id INT,col1 CHAR(9),col2 CHAR(9),col3 INT)

INSERT INTO tab(id, fk_id, col1, col2, col3)
VALUES
(1,10020,'a','b',100),
(2,10020,'a2','b2',NULL),
(3,10020,'a3',NULL,300),
(4,10020,NULL, 'b4',400),
(5,10020,NULL, NULL,500),
(6,10020,NULL, NULL,NULL),
(7,10020,'a7','b7', 700);

SELECT * FROM tab where fk_id=10020;

┌────┬───────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ id │ fk_id │ col1 │ col2 │ col3 │
├────┼───────┼──────┼──────┼──────┤
│  1 │ 10020 │ a    │ b    │ 100  │
│  2 │ 10020 │ a2   │ b2   │ null │
│  3 │ 10020 │ a3   │ null │ 300  │
│  4 │ 10020 │ null │ b4   │ 400  │
│  5 │ 10020 │ null │ null │ 500  │
│  6 │ 10020 │ null │ null │ null │
│  7 │ 10020 │ a7   │ b7   │ 700  │
└────┴───────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

And final query:

```
SELECT * FROM tab t1 NATURAL JOIN tab t2 WHERE t1.fk_id=10020;

┌────┬───────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ id │ fk_id │ col1 │ col2 │ col3 │
├────┼───────┼──────┼──────┼──────┤
│  1 │ 10020 │ a    │ b    │  100 │
│  7 │ 10020 │ a7   │ b7   │  700 │
└────┴───────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=49d1606c2ab1f6339056f0e833c73367)**

---

> *As far as I know you can't automatize at SQL level. May be wrinting of small method at java\php\python (whatever you use) will help you*- @xander27

Another approach could be prepared statement and building SQL query based on `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` metadata.

```
SET @s = 
(SELECT CONCAT('SELECT * FROM tab WHERE fk_id=? ',
        GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('AND ',COLUMN_NAME, ' IS NOT NULL ') SEPARATOR ''))
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tab');

PREPARE stmt2 FROM @s;
SET @a = 10020;
EXECUTE stmt2 USING @a;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ffa31800c67cbd912bd963038b1790c7)**