# How to ignore coulmns that have null values and only get columns that are not null

Tags: mysql, sql

My table looks like this:
[image]

So I don't know how to exclude the null columns and get other column data.
Like when I try to get data of id = 1, I want to exclude null columns(name) and get other columns(id, email, and address) data. Similarly, when I try to data of id = 3, I want to exclude columns(address) and get other columns(id, email, and name) data only.

Comment: So you want a 3 column result for id = 1 and 4 column result for id = 2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclude lines results that have NULL value in any field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11795340/exclude-lines-results-that-have-null-value-in-any-field). Or [MySQL SELECT only not null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285448/mysql-select-only-not-null-values)

Comment: In general, one query will return a result set with a *fixed* "shape" - the number of columns, their names and types. Are you sure trying to solve this at the *sql* level is the right thing to do? I'd suggest you leave such a *presentation* concern to your presentation/reporting layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can not exclude columns when only a few values are null on a dataset like yours. But try :

```
SELECT ISNULL(name, '') as name FROM TABLE_NAME
```